# Setting up Google Recaptcha with Mobius Forms

Tags: 2sxc, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to create a reasonably simple Mobious Form to gather new client information for a counselling service.
I want to implement Recaptcha, but I'm not getting very far. It points me to Global Settings, and I'm assuming I have to create some custom settings, but I've got not idea what settings to create, or then how to implement the recaptcha in the form. Some pointers to some up to date doco would be really helpful, if any exist.

Answer (score 0):

These are very normal settings in each form:
[image]

You won't see the recaptcha, as V3 of Recaptcha can be made invisible ;)